# How to correctly add icon or image to each menu item inside Mahapp DropDownButton

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I am using [Mahapp's DropDownButton](https://mahapps.com/controls/split_dropdownbutton.html)

Here is what I have:

using

```
 xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"

<mah:DropDownButton 
    Content="my button" 
    Icon="{DynamicResource appbar_projector_screen}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MySource}">
    <mah:DropDownButton.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=Command}"/>
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=Id }"/>
            <Setter Property="Icon">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Image Width="25" Height="25" Source="{Binding IconPath}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </mah:DropDownButton.ItemContainerStyle>
</mah:DropDownButton>
```

First I tried using:

```
<Setter Property="Header">
    <Setter.Value>
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="{Binding IconPath}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

But that code does not show any image. So then I tried:

```
<Setter Property="Icon">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Image Width="25" Height="25" Source="{Binding IconPath}" />
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Initializing the Object `MySource`:

```
public List<SomeDefinition> MySource{ get; private set; }

MySource= new List<SomeDefinition>
{
    new SomeDefinition{Id=1, Title= $@"1", Command = new RelayCommand<object>(SomeMethod1), IconPath = "D:\\ico1.png"},
    new SomeDefinition{Id=2, Title= $@"2", Command = new RelayCommand<object>(SomeMethod2), IconPath = "D:\\ico2.png"},
    new SomeDefinition{Id=3, Title= $@"3", Command = new RelayCommand<object>(SomeMethod3), IconPath = "D:\\ico3.png"},
    new SomeDefinition{Id=4, Title= $@"4", Command = new RelayCommand<object>(SomeMethod4), IconPath = "D:\\ico4.png"},
    new SomeDefinition{Id=5, Title= $@"5", Command = new RelayCommand<object>(SomeMethod5), IconPath = "D:\\ico5.png"}
};
```

having:

```
public class SomeDefinition
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title{ get; set; }
        public ICommand Command { get; set; }
        public string IconPath { get; set; }
    }
```

This shows image **only for the last value** on menu, I can´t figure out what I am missing. Why is it showing only image for last record?

I tested with all images and they are written correctly, they also do exist, so issue is not finding the image file .

## Update

So I have tried using @mm8 solution and changed definition Class to:

```
public class SomeDefinition
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title{ get; set; }
        public ICommand Command { get; set; }
        public Image IconImage { get; set; }

    }
```

having xaml:

```
<mah:DropDownButton 
    Content="my button" 
    Icon="{DynamicResource appbar_projector_screen}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MySource}">
    <mah:DropDownButton.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=Command}"/>
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=Id }"/>
            <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding IconImage}" />          
        </Style>
    </mah:DropDownButton.ItemContainerStyle>
</mah:DropDownButton>
```

and code behind:

```
var Image = new Bitmap(@"D:\\1.png");



MySource = new List<SomeDefinition>
{
    new SomeDefinition{Id=1, Title= $@"1", Command = Command1, IconImage = Image},
    new SomeDefinition{Id=2, Title= $@"2", Command = Command2, IconImage = Image},
    new SomeDefinition{Id=3, Title= $@"3", Command = Command3, IconImage = Image},
    new SomeDefinition{Id=4, Title= $@"4", Command = Command4, IconImage = Image},
    new SomeDefinition{Id=5, Title= $@"5", Command = Command5, IconImage = Image}
};
```

Result is:
[image]

How to convert object to Image?

Comment: Did you try to bind the `Icon` property to your `IconPath` source property?: `<Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding IconPath}">`

Comment: @mm8 if I do that I do get urlPath displayed for all menu items, but I want the image not url, that happens because I use image source...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"This shows image only for the last value on menu" - Setter creates only one instance of Image, which can only be displayed in one place.

As a workaround you can declare Image as a non-shared resource, and use it via StaticResource in Setter:

```
<Image x:Key="StdIcon" x:Shared="False" Width="25" Height="25" Source="{Binding IconPath}" />

<Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource StdIcon}"/>
```

Comment: Where should I add the Image  declaration?

Comment: in the Resources, before Style. `<Resources> <Image ... /> <Style><Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource StdIcon}"/></Style>`