# WPF Switch ToggleButton Content

Tags: wpf, xaml, togglebutton

I've defined the following xaml for a toggle button

```
<ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource AppMenuVisibilityToggleButtonDark}"
              IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsVisible, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

with the style

```
<Style x:Key="AppMenuVisibilityToggleButtonDark" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="HideOutline"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
             <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                 <Setter Property="Content">
                     <Setter.Value>
                         <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ShowOutline"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
```

However, when I have multiple use cases of this button, i.e., the xaml button is used in as part of an ItemTemplate in a ListBox, the content randomly just disappears only to reappear again when I click on the toggle button, but that then causes one of the other toggle button's content to disappear (see below where bottom item doesn't display any content for the "visibility" eye icon).

[image]

Given how my style is set up, I don't see how the content should ever just disappear. Am I missing something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59259554/1506454

Comment: Bit confused, if I remove the icons and replace with a TextBlock, e.g, change `<materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="HideOutline"/>` to  `<TextBlock Text="HideOutline"/>` I still get the same problem, so don't think it is related to the icon (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: did you read the answer? it is not related to the exact type of UIElement

Comment: Got it. Yes, that does make sense.