# Creating objects in styles multiple times

Tags: wpf

Let's say I have a lot of button declarations in WPF. These button declarations are very similar and vary only by one property. Here's some example code:

```
<Button x:Name="Button1"
        ...>
    <Image Source="{StaticResource ButtonImage}"
           Style="{StaticResource ButtonImageStyle}" />
</Button>

<Button x:Name="Button2"
        ...>
    <Image Source="{StaticResource ButtonImage}"
           Style="{StaticResource ButtonImageStyle}" />
</Button> 

<Button x:Name="Button3"
        ...>
    <Image Source="{StaticResource ButtonImage}"
           Style="{StaticResource ButtonImageStyle}" />
</Button> 

<Button x:Name="Button4"
        ...>
    <Image Source="{StaticResource ButtonImage}"
           Style="{StaticResource ButtonImageStyle}" />
</Button>

<Button x:Name="Button5"
        ...>
    <Image Source="{StaticResource ButtonImage}"
           Style="{StaticResource ButtonImageStyle}" />
</Button>
```

All these buttons look the same, they just vary by their name.

Since all the properties of the button are the same (except for the name) I created a style containing all the properties that are the same and used that style in all of my buttons.

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="..." Value="..." />
</Style>

<Button x:Name="Button1"
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle">
    <Image Source="{StaticResource ButtonImage}"
           Style="{StaticResource ButtonImageStyle}" />
</Button>

<Button x:Name="Button2"
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle">
    <Image Source="{StaticResource ButtonImage}"
           Style="{StaticResource ButtonImageStyle}" />
</Button> 

<Button x:Name="Button3"
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle">
    <Image Source="{StaticResource ButtonImage}"
           Style="{StaticResource ButtonImageStyle}" />
</Button> 

<Button x:Name="Button4"
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle">
    <Image Source="{StaticResource ButtonImage}"
           Style="{StaticResource ButtonImageStyle}" />
</Button>

<Button x:Name="Button5"
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle">
    <Image Source="{StaticResource ButtonImage}"
           Style="{StaticResource ButtonImageStyle}" />
</Button>
```

Everything works fine so far.

Now, since even the image is the same on all the buttons, I wanted to move this image to the style as well.

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="..." Value="..." />
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Image Source="{StaticResource ButtonImage}"
                   Style="{StaticResource ButtonImageStyle}" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Button x:Name="Button1"
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle" />

<Button x:Name="Button2"
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle" />

<Button x:Name="Button3"
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle" />

<Button x:Name="Button4"
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle" />

<Button x:Name="Button5"
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle" />
```

But now I only see the image on the current active button, all the other buttons don't show the image. I guess with moving the image to the style it is only created in memory once and therefore it can be only shown once.

Is there a way to tell WPF, that an object created in a style should be created separately for every  object that uses this style?

Comment: I have previously offered an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59263082/1506454) to similar question, but in your case I would suggest custom template for Button - Image included in template - like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18481787/1506454)

Comment: I thought about that myself but I wanted to avoid a custom template with all the triggers and stuff.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you.

The `x:Shared` solution mentioned in two answers didn't work, at least not in the code I had to maintain.

But I found a `ContentTemplate` property with the button, and putting my `Image` inside a `DataTemplate` and putting this `DataTemplate` into my style worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create each time new image, for it wouldn't be destroyed. So put `x:Shared="false"`:

```
<Image x:Key="ButtonImage" x:Shared="false".. />
```

to the image resource definition, this should do th trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the `Image` as a separate non-shared resource:

```
<Image x:Key="img" x:Shared="false" Source="{StaticResource ButtonImage}" 
    Style="{StaticResource ButtonImageStyle}" />
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource img}" />
</Style>
```